# Kotling :: Android :: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, dagger-2

I am getting an exception in the first line of the code below

```
viewModel.homeLiveData.observe(this, Observer { list ->

        list?.let {
            mList.addAll(list)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

The Whole code is Below

what is wrong with the cast ? is there anything wrong of I am creating my ViewModel?

My BaseActivity

```
  abstract class BaseActivity<V : ViewModel> : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var fragmentAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @LayoutRes
    abstract fun layoutRes(): Int

    protected lateinit var viewModel : V

    protected abstract fun getViewModel() : Class<V>

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == android.R.id.home)
            onBackPressed()

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(layoutRes())
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(getViewModel())
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> = fragmentAndroidInjector
}
```

then My Activity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<MainViewModel>() {


override fun layoutRes(): Int = R.layout.activity_main

override fun getViewModel(): Class<MainViewModel> = MainViewModel::class.java

private val mList = mutableListOf<Any>()

private lateinit var adapter: DataAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

   // setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 2)
        adapter = DataAdapter(context, mList)

    }

    viewModel.homeLiveData.observe(this, Observer { list ->

        list?.let {
            mList.addAll(list)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })

    viewModel.getHomeItems()


}
```

and this is my ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {


val homeLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<HomeScreenModel>> = MutableLiveData()


fun getHomeItems() {

    Handler().post {

        val homeModleList = listOf(
            HomeScreenModel(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, MyApplication.instance.getString(R.string.settings))
        )

        homeLiveData.setValue(homeModleList)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Nothing was wrong with the viewModel. the issue was from adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: what was your fix? I think I am having a similar issue...

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I am getting similaar error
`class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel$Subclass1 cannot be cast to class`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your `viewModel` property, which you try to access in `viewModel.homeLiveData` is shadowed by `getViewModel()` abstract function that you declare in `BaseActivity`. This is because Kotlin thinks that `getXyZ()` is a getter for the field `xyZ` and thus when you access `viewModel`, the compiler thinks you want to call `getViewModel`, which is of type `Class<V>`. I suggest renaming either the function or the property and it should work then.

Comment: the error has nothing to do with the viewModel :S 
I have removed *adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()* from the list?.let  and it worked and the list got populated  .
what do i have wrong with my adapter ? do i have something wrong with it instance ?

Comment: That exception you posted certainly does nothing to do with the adapter. The next thing is that you never assign a `lateinit var adapter` in your code. You were probably getting `UninitializedPropertyException` because inside `recyclerView.apply` you are setting rv's `adapter` not your lateinit property.

Answer (score 0):

Check your viewModel factory if you implemented it correctly

Comment: Nothing was wrong with the viewModel. the issue was from adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()